# Query to filter by a count

Tags: sql, oracle

Given these tables:

```
Employee(ssn, name, sex, address, salary, bdate, dno, superssn)
fk:superssn is ssn in Employee
fk:dno is dnumber in Department

Department(dnumber, dname, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)
fk:mgrssn is ssn in Employee

Dept_locations(dnumber, dlocation)
fk:dnumber is dnumber in Department

Project(pnumber, pname, plocation, dnum)
fk:dnum is dnumber in Department

Dependent(essn, dependent_name, sex, bdate, relationship)
fk: essn is ssn in Employee

Works_on(essn,pno,hours)
fk: essn is ssn in Employee; pno is pnumber in Project
```

I need to retrive the name of each department as well as the departments manger's name for departments that have two locations...

I have this query so far

```
SELECT D.dname, D.mgrssn
FROM department D, dept_locations DL
WHERE D.dnumber = dl.dnumber
Group by D.dname, D.mgrssn
```

I now get the three non duplicating departments. How do I restrict this to departments which have two locations?

Comment: *"real quick please"* = homework ?

Comment: thanks for the editing job lol, when I looked at it I saw how horrible it was >_<

Comment: You should try using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: Think of what your query will return now (without the `AND...`, delete that). For every departmnet with 3 locations, it will return 3 rows. For every department with 1 location, 1 row. So, you have to "group by" department to gather all rows of a department into one row (and count them if you need to). This is the usual way to deal with data that are split over more than one rows.

Comment: oooo thank you :D:D I think i can get it now :D

Comment: what if I need to show the people who only work on 1 project... another hw question...how should that be constructed

Comment: Have you done the first one? You can edit your question and add your solution in the end.

Comment: to a point, it shows which but I don't know how to only show which have more than 2

Comment: Please clarify: "I need to retrive the name of each department as well as the departments manger's name for departments that have two locations..."... but your query only returns the `mgrssn` - which value do you actually want in the result?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT D.dname, D.mgrssn
FROM Department D, Dept_locations DL
WHERE D.dnumber = DL.dnumber
GROUP BY D.dname, D.mgrssn
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2            --- for 2 or more locations
```

and it's better to use `INNER JOIN` (or simply `JOIN` )instead of `WHERE` for joining related tables. Note the diference from the previous query. Both will return same results :

```
SELECT D.dname, D.mgrssn
FROM Department D
    JOIN Dept_locations DL
        ON D.dnumber = DL.dnumber
GROUP BY D.dname, D.mgrssn
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

If you also want to show the manager's name, you'll have to join the Employee table as well (and group accordingly):

```
SELECT D.dname
     , D.mgrssn
     , E.name
FROM Department D
    JOIN Employee E 
        ON E.ssn = D.mgrssn
    JOIN Dept_locations DL
        ON D.dnumber = DL.dnumber
GROUP BY D.dname
       , D.mgrssn
       , E.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: @Joel: Every department has exactly one manager. See the tables definitions.

Comment: DEPARTMENT has a `mgrstartdate`, so there are more than one managers associated from a historical perspective.  Also, ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 INNER JOIN syntax produces the same query plan; it's just preferable to use ANSI-92 syntax for sake of OUTER JOINs.

Comment: @OMG: Agreed about the Joins. This is homework however, so it's not a matter of better plan or best practise but playing in teacher's terms (which should be same as best practise terms ...)

Comment: @OMG: About the mgrstartdate, I guessed that there is only one manager (the current) stored in every department.

Answer (score 1):

For exactly two locations:

```
SELECT d.name AS dept_name,
       e.name AS mgr_name
  FROM DEPARTMENT d
  JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.ssn = d.mgrssn
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM DEPT_LOCATIONS dl
                WHERE dl.dnumber = d.dnumber
             GROUP BY dl.dnumber
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

For two or more locations:

```
SELECT d.name AS dept_name,
       e.name AS mgr_name
  FROM DEPARTMENT d
  JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.ssn = d.mgrssn
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM DEPT_LOCATIONS dl
                WHERE dl.dnumber = d.dnumber
             GROUP BY dl.dnumber
               HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
```

#### Keep in mind

The `DEPARTMENT` table has a `mgrstartdate`, so you'll need to check against it -- the two examples I provided will show you all the historical managers in addition to the current managers because there's no filtering on the `mgrstartdate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select dname, name
from Department, Employee, Dept_locations
where mgrssn = ssn
and Department.dnumber = Dept_locations.dnumber
```

Comment: you will have one line for each location, with a duplicate department. if you need to concat the locations, use custom functions, but i doubt your teacher told you how to use them. so this will do the trick.